# How to show a dialog fragment from within custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show a dialog whenever someone clicks an image from one of the rows in a customized listview.  How should I go about doing this?  Here's what I've implemented so far in my custom adapter.  See the "*How to show dialog fragment ???*" comment in the code for where I'm stumped.

```
public class DirectoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private final Session mSession;
private final ArrayList<MyObject> mMyObjects;

public DirectoryAdapter(Context context, Session session, ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects) {
    mContext = context;
    mSession = session;
    mMyObjects= myObjects;
}

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = null;

    try {
        if (convertView == null) {

            view = new View(mContext);   
            // get row item from directory_item.xml
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.server_row, null);
            view.setLongClickable(true);
        } else {
            view = (View) convertView;              
        }

        //Info button
        ImageView info = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_directory_item_options);

        info.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                        ServerMenuDialog dialog = new ServerMenuDialog();
                dialog.setRetainInstance(true);
// How to show dialog fragment ???
                        dialog.show(view.getContext(), "Server Menu");  //EXAMPLE -- WONT COMPILE  there is no such view.getContext() method
            }

        });

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //TODO error handling
    } finally {
        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: why not use this.context rather than view.getContext() ?

Comment: @Pheonixblade little correction: this.mContext

Comment: @Pheonixblade -- this.mContext is not the appropriate scope for this call.  'This' seems to reference the view and not the DirectoryAdapter class.  I can't seem to get a reference to FragmentManager from just 'mContext' so I'm a bit stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is a good idea to show the Dialog from inside your adapter class. I think you should instead override the OnClick method for your activity class and implement OnItemClickListener. This works fine when you click on listView element. I am not sure if it will be also good to distinguish which View of the selected element did you actually click (as I understand you are just interested in clicking an image), but you could probably find this out. Anyways, you should add

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

In my aplication I use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    //Change part below with your code
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = callback.fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
    ObjectFragment fragment = new ObjectFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("position", position);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_log_reader_relativeLayout1, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit(); 
    //---End of change
}
```

In your case, instead of creating a new fragment, you should create new Dialog.

Comment: what is `callback` ?